# Passing Variables to Subprocess.Popen to run copy command

Tags: python, subprocess, popen3

**I have a script which runs copy command to copy files and directories. Since, i have arguments stored in variables.**

```py
copy_cmd = ['Lang=en_US' , '/bin/cp' , '-r' , '-v']

Option['source']

Option['destination']
```

**I'm passing the value of Option['source'] & Option['destination'] at run time.
I'am unable to perform the command and getting....**

```
child exception
AttributeError: list object has no attribute rfind
```

**The command which i'am using is**

```py
copy_pid = subprocess.Popen([copy_cmd , Option['source'] , '/.' , 'Option['destination']'] , stdin = subprocess.PIPE , stdout = subprocess.PIPE)
```

Comment: What is Option? Is it a dict? Is it a list? If you do `print(type(Option['source']))` what do you get? And if you did `print(Option['source'])` what do you see?

Comment: Basically, you need to make sure everything you're passing in is correct. This command works: `subprocess.Popen(["echo", "hello", "world"])` And so you need to pass a list in. Also, you could attempt `shell=True` if you require your command to be run in a shell. Please give us more information.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass lis of strings yet `copy_cmd` is already a list. So you meed to concatenate it and not insert as an element.

```py
copy_pid = subprocess.Popen(copy_cmd + [Option['source'] , '/.' , Option['destination']] , stdin = subprocess.PIPE , stdout = subprocess.PIPE)
```

Also I don't understand what are those `Option` for so I just left them as they were.

Comment: Wouldn't this literally just work: `copy_cmd = ['Lang=en_US' , '/bin/cp' , '-r' , '-v', Option["source"], Option["destination"]]`? :/

Comment: For this case yes. But I think that is not exact answer and if the question is simplified then not exact answer may not be applicable. So I don't try guessing authors intentions I just try to anwser the question asked the best I can.

Comment: copy_cmd = ['Lang=en_US' , '/bin/cp' , '-r' , '-v', Option["source"], Option["destination"]] 


I already tried this way, but it gets me an error. Below is the error:
raise child exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

However, i tried  this   copy_cmd = [ '/bin/cp' , '-r' , '-v', Option["source"], Option["destination"]]


and it worked fine.

Option["source"] and  Option["destination"]]  contains the path of different directories in string format.

Comment: It did n't work because it tried to run file `'Lang=en_US'`. Why did you even add `'Lang=en_US'`?